# Remove prettiers from typescript project

Tags: typescript, prettier

I have to much prettier in my project and it implicit a lot of problems.

I want to stay with prettier@2.1.2

Do You know how can i delete od disable other prettier's ?

[image: To much prettier]

Comment: Please be more specific. What problems are you having?

Comment: @AluanHaddad like you can see upside, i have 8 prettier's in my project. I Want have only 1 prettier@2.1.2. I dont know how uninstal or delete prettiers: 
@ant-design/pro-cli - prettier@2.0.5
@svgr/core@3.1.0 - prettier@1.19.1 etc.

Comment: You can't because they are dependencies of your dependencies. It shouldn't actually cause you any problems. Note that your package manager will the duplicate where possible. That is to say when your dependencies share compatible version ranges

Comment: Note that if you are using prettier you should install your own version independently. It should be one of your direct dependencies